# How do you check the current duplex value of a network card set to Auto negotiate in Windows?

Tags: windows, networking, network-adapter, duplex

I would like to know what duplex (half or full) my network card has negotiated with a switch when they are both set to auto configuration in Windows.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

At command prompt:

```
powershell "Get-NetAdapter | SELECT name, fullduplex | where name -eq 'card name'"
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Looks like the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968170(v=vs.85).aspx confirms that this is the operating status not the selected setting.  Glad to see that there is now a way to do this 8 years later reliably.

Comment: Get-NetAdapter needs Windows 8 or later (re: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27213645/)

Answer (score 11):

Without looking at the switch, the only way it seems possible is if the windows driver for your NIC reports this information.  To see if it does, go to `Control Panel --> Administrator Tools --> Event Viewer`.  You then want to look at the *System* logs (in Windows7 this is under the *Windows Logs* tree).  Once you found the System logs, click on *Source* at the top to use as the sorting criteria.  Now look for your NIC driver, mine for example is *b57nd60a*.  Scroll through all the entries that your NIC driver has made and if you're lucky you'll see what speed it negotiated at in the event report.

Comment: This is a pain in the ass, but it works, thanks.  I sorted by Source, and found b57w2k (for a BroadCom chip) and then looked at the history of it configuring it self.

Comment: +1. Worked for me. Searched for my NIC brand name (Marvell in this case) and jumped right to it.

Answer (score 8):

Type the following into command prompt:

```
wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed
```

It should tell you.

Comment: Could you provide sample output?

Comment: This worked great for me in Windows 10!  Thanks.

Comment: That doesn't appear to list whether or not it negotiated at full-duplex.  Perhaps "get Name,Speed,AutoSense" gives that to you?

Answer (score 7):

With Powershell run:

```
Get-NetAdapter | SELECT name, LinkSpeed, fullduplex | ft -autosize
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Some cards (Intel for example) have a diagnostic suite that shows this information. This software is often not installed.  Usually just the driver is installed and the diagnostic/management app is not. I believe the Intel app is called ProSet

Answer (score 2):

This works in Windows 7, not sure about lower versions:

1. Right click on the network card in Network Connections in the Control Panel
2. Click **Configure**
3. Click the **Link Speed** Tab
4. Look at the **Link status** Window.

[image]

Comment: This one would work with lower versions of Windows but it is relevant only to certain network card drivers. Basic drivers and most drivers from other manufacturers than Intel will not show the information.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's easy to see the speed 10/100/1000Mbps, windows tells you and the LEDs tell you, the person was asking about Full/Half duplex, which can be at any connection speed 10/100/1000Mbps.

Answer (score -1):

There is no *software-way* to report the duplex mode negotiated(especially with a switch) because all of those things happen on the physical layer.

You will need some kind of measurement device to diagnose that *electronically*.

Comment: I waffled between serverfault and superuser, imo it's suitable for both, if the mod's think otherwise I wouldn't object.

Comment: `ethtool` does it on Linux, so software interfaces to get to the info exists.

Comment: It depend on OS driver model. If it in windows fully leaved on drivers, than OS no necessarily have such information.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest way I can think of is to get a switch that has lights on the front or a management interface and simply take a look.

Other than that, I am not really aware of any software able to tell you.

Answer (score -1):

On my Windows 7 Platform -

- List item

Type at the Windows 7 search bar Network and Sharing Center. 
 Select -  Network and Sharing Center

> Change Adapter Settings
>
> Right Click ( The LAN Lannetwrk Adapter) select Status it will show you the speed you have negotiated with the next network device up stream.

Comment: Link speed is unfortunately not the same as Duplex.  It is possible to be Half Duplex 100mbps for example.

Answer (score -1):

There's no need to spend an hour in the event viewer :

Inside "Network Connections", right click -> "Status".

Here you can see "Speed".

[image: step 1]

[image: step 2]

Comment: Unfortunately Speed does not indicate the status of Duplex in ethernet on Windows.  It is entirely possible to be 1.0 Gbps and half-duplex

Comment: There's actually no such thing as half-duplex gigabit Ethernet.

Comment: @NicolasMelay https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gigabit_Ethernet half-duplex is a thing in 1000Base-T and unfortunately I have seen it in the wild due to cable damage and auto-negotiate.  Which is what prompted this question originally.