# Wireless connection faster and more stable than Ethernet connection

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, connection

My system specs:

- OS: Windows 10, 64-Bit
- CPU: Intel i7 - 6800K CPU @ 3.40 GHz
- RAM: 32 GB
- GPU: Nvidia GTX 1070
- MB: MSI x99A SLI Plus

My wireless adapter on both 2.4 and 5G wireless puts out over 117 Mbps speed test, but when wired directly into the Ethernet port I can get only about 10 Mbps. I have tried 4 different CAT5 Ethernet cables to make sure it wasn't a wire issue, and tried them in all 4 ports as well.

My router is a brand new Nighthawk 7000 Router. Ethernet drivers are up to date and working properly. I can't understand how my wireless is faster and more stable than my wired connection.

So to put it quite simply. How can I get a wired Ethernet connection at 100 Mbps like I can with my wireless connection? Why can I only get 10 Mbps?

Comment: Have you tried sharing a file between to pcs and check that speed?

Comment: Yes I have. Same slow connection.

Comment: Weird that this was put on hold.... It's very clear what you are asking.

Comment: Out of curiosity - do you have a different cable? Maybe you happen to have a bad cable?

Comment: I'd go with the bad cable. I've had that happen with a dodgy, strange cable before.

Answer (score 0):

You can check you speed negociation to know the state of your network card.

> powershell "Get-NetAdapter | SELECT name, fullduplex | where name -eq
>   ‘card name’"

source: [How do you check the current duplex value of a network card set to Auto negotiate in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/86581/how-do-you-check-the-current-duplex-value-of-a-network-card-set-to-auto-negotiat)