# the cmd Command Lind : wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed

Tags: command-line

I am trying using the command:  wmic NIC where NetEnabled=true get Name, Speed    does not inform me about the duplex (Auto, 100Mbps Fullduplex, 100Mbps Half Duplex etc.)

How Can i be informed about the adapter setting DUPLEX????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you check the current duplex value of a network card set to Auto negotiate in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/86581/how-do-you-check-the-current-duplex-value-of-a-network-card-set-to-auto-negotiat)

Comment: What info DO you get from wmic? What command(s) are you running? What research have you done?